# Image generation in a New Window

Tags: c++, image, visual-studio-2022

I am making a program that will send a custom notification sent for whatever I want. I have a window that shows up on the screen, but the image doesn't load.

I have tried using Chat GPT to check my code, but with its knowledge limit being Sept 2021 it doesn't know the new updates to API's to give me a correct response.

Code can be found below:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Shellapi.h>
 
// Constants
#define WM_CLOSENOTIFICATION (WM_USER + 1)
#define BUTTON_OPENURL_ID 100
#define BUTTON_CLOSE_ID 101
#define IDB_NOTIFICATION_BITMAP 108 // Replace with your bitmap resource ID
 
// Global variables
HWND hMainWindow;
HWND hNotificationWindow;
HBITMAP hBitmap;
 
// Function to create and show the notification window
void ShowNotification()
{
    // Get the screen dimensions
    int screenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    int screenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
 
    // Calculate the center position for the notification window
    int notificationWidth = 400; // Set your desired width
    int notificationHeight = 200; // Set your desired height
    int notificationX = (screenWidth - notificationWidth) / 2;
    int notificationY = (screenHeight - notificationHeight) / 2;
 
    // Create the custom notification window
    hNotificationWindow = CreateWindow(
        L"NotificationWindowClass",         // Class name
        L"Custom Notification",             // Window title
        WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER,  // Window styles
        notificationX, notificationY,        // Position
        notificationWidth, notificationHeight,   // Size
        nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr   // Parent window, Menu handle, Instance, Additional data
    );
 
    // Load the bitmap resource
    hBitmap = LoadBitmap(GetModuleHandle(nullptr), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_NOTIFICATION_BITMAP));
    if (hBitmap == nullptr)
    {
        OutputDebugStringA("Error Bitmap Null Value");
        // Display appropriate error message or take necessary actions
    }
 
    // Create a static control for the image
    HWND hImageStatic = CreateWindow(
        L"STATIC",                      // Window class name
        nullptr,                        // Text content (empty for image)
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_BITMAP | SS_CENTERIMAGE,  // Window styles
        10, 10, notificationWidth - 20, notificationHeight - 20, // Position and size
        hNotificationWindow, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr  // Parent window, Menu handle, Instance, Additional data
    );
    SendMessage(hImageStatic, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(hBitmap));
 
    // Create a button to open a website
    HWND hOpenButton = CreateWindow(
        L"BUTTON",                      // Window class name
        L"Open Website",                // Text content
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_CENTER | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,  // Window styles
        10, notificationHeight - 60, (notificationWidth - 40) / 2, 30, // Position and size
        hNotificationWindow, reinterpret_cast<HMENU>(BUTTON_OPENURL_ID), nullptr, nullptr  // Parent window, Menu handle, Instance, Additional data
    );
 
    // Create a button to close the notification
    HWND hCloseButton = CreateWindow(
        L"BUTTON",                      // Window class name
        L"Close",                       // Text content
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_CENTER | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,  // Window styles
        20 + (notificationWidth - 40) / 2, notificationHeight - 60, (notificationWidth - 40) / 2, 30, // Position and size
        hNotificationWindow, reinterpret_cast<HMENU>(BUTTON_CLOSE_ID), nullptr, nullptr  // Parent window, Menu handle, Instance, Additional data
    );
}
 
// Window procedure for the notification window
LRESULT CALLBACK NotificationWindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        // Handle command messages
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == BUTTON_OPENURL_ID)
        {
            // Open a website when the button is clicked
            ShellExecute(nullptr, L"open", L"https://example.com", nullptr, nullptr, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
        }
        else if (LOWORD(wParam) == BUTTON_CLOSE_ID)
        {
            // Show the main window again
            ShowWindow(hMainWindow, SW_SHOW);
            // Clean up and exit the notification window
            DestroyWindow(hNotificationWindow);
        }
        break;
 
    case WM_CLOSE:
        // Show the main window again
        ShowWindow(hMainWindow, SW_SHOW);
        // Clean up and exit the notification window
        DestroyWindow(hNotificationWindow);
        break;
    }
 
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
 
// Entry point
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    // Create and register the window class for the notification window
    WNDCLASS wc = {};
    wc.lpfnWndProc = NotificationWindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"NotificationWindowClass";
    RegisterClass(&wc);
 
    // Create the main window
    hMainWindow = CreateWindow(
        L"MainWindowClass",             // Window class name
        L"Main Window",                 // Window title
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window styles
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,   // Position
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,   // Size
        nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr   // Parent window, Menu handle, Instance, Additional data
    );
 
    // Show the main window
    ShowWindow(hMainWindow, nCmdShow);
 
    // Show the initial notification
    ShowNotification();
 
    // Message loop
    MSG msg = {};
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
 
    // Clean up resources
    if (hBitmap != nullptr)
    {
        DeleteObject(hBitmap);
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

Update: Here is a screenshot of my .rc file in VS. I have to see if I can find the file in my source files.

[.rc file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9vc2.jpg)

And here is what the program currently makes when you run it.

[Program Execution Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkLN2.png)

Comment: No errors just doesn't load the image. If I add error handling to the check if the Bitmap = null than it will supply the error code

Comment: post you .rc file.

Answer (score 1):

Switched over to GDI + instead of Bitmaps and it worked instantly.

Thank you for trying to help @jwezorek.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).